# Android Json Handling issue

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio

I want to display updated_at  data to user only if value of password in folder Array is null.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject dataa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                JSONArray jsonArray2 = dataa.getJSONArray("folder");
                                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray.length(); i2++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject dataa2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i2);
                                    String password = dataa2.getString("password");
                                    if (password.equals("null") || password.equals(null))
                                    {
                                        //Display data
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        // dont Display data
                                    }
}
```

[image: Check the Json Response Here]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray.length(); i2++)` change to  `for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray2.length(); i2++)`

Comment: Hahaha, What a silly mistake to spend time on
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectify your inner loop condition section.

```
JSONArray jsonArray2 = dataa.getJSONArray("folder");
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray2.length(); i2++)
          {
              JSONObject dataa2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i2);
```

Comment: Hahaha, What a silly mistake to spend time on
Thanks a lot